# How to convert a string number with text into numeric number

Tags: php

I have a number like that : 342.50 EUR. How to table only the number : 342.50
I tried this, but it's not the result that I want

```
$str = '342.50 EUR';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

result : `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 342 [1] => 00 ) )`

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with losing the last `0` then you can simply use [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

```
$str = '342.50 EUR';

echo floatval($str); // 342.5
```

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this ...

```
$str = +'342.50 EUR';
```

or

```
$str = '342.50 EUR';
$str = +$str;
```

This way, no need to know about the type of number (int or float).

This is a compact version of `0 + '342.50 EUR'`. PHP will cast the string to the first number part it can find in it. If no number is there, then it will result to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast it to a float :

```
$str = '342.50 EUR';    
$float = floatval($str);
```

And after, you can chose the number of decimals to show with number_format :

```
echo(number_format($float, 2));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in two steps:

1. Remove the currency name from the string.
2. Then convert the remaining string into a float value.

These steps can be performed in these lines:

```
$string = '342.50 EUR';
$string = str_replace(" EUR", "", $string);
$float_value_of_string = floatval($string);
echo $float_value_of_string; //342.50
```